# Should I use join table as object

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am creating a web app where users can bookmark movies.

I have three tables - `Movies`, `Bookmarks` and `Users`.

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Bookmark
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public int Review { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
}
```

Should I use the bookmark as a join table, or have two other join tables:

`UserBookmark` and `BookmarkMovies`?

I'm still a beginner with programming and SQL methodologies so sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: Do you use ef or tsql?you join depends on your expected (if you want whole of movies of  user,you must join user with bookmarks and bookmarks with movie.

Comment: The word "join" is typically used to reference a SQL query option to find the intersection of data between two or more tables. Using a join depends on the purpose of your programming. Other concepts to consider are primary and foreign keys in your data tables. For example, you may want to define a foreign key in the Bookmark table to ensure that only known movies as defined in the Movie table can be referenced (stored in) the Bookmark table. Your database and software design depends on the assigned requirements.

Comment: If one bookmark can have multiple movies than you need another class BookmarkMovies

Comment: Yyou *don't* need a `BookmarkMovies` class at all. You'd need one only if the relation was M:N. [The join table will  be generated by EF Core itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many). Join tables are only needed in many-many relations. In one-many you can put the parent ID in multiple child ID rows. Before EF Core 7, you'd have to explicitly create a join entity, eg `PostTags` in the documentation example. In EF Core 7 the entity is no longer needed. You can use an existing join table or specify one with a different name that the conventional one